# Change "User Defined Variables" based on external variable

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am having some trouble trying to change User Defined Variables based on an already existing variable.

**BeanShell:**

```
String databaseSize;

if (${__P(DBsize,${DB_size})} == '0') {
vars.put("databaseSize","SmallDB"); }
    else if (${__P(DBsize,${DB_size})} == '1') 
    {vars.put("databaseSize","LargeDB");}
```

**User Defined Variables**

Name: path

Value: ${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}\ **${databaseSize}**

I would like to change the *path* based on what I store in *databaseSize*. I have two folders in the given path: SmallDB and LargeDB. As far as I know, UDV are getting assigned before JMeter manages to run my BeanShell.

Is there an alternative way of changing the *path* based on another variable (received from Jenkins or default value received from a file)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting mainly because [Groovy performance is much better than Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) and friends
2. You can put [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) directly into `Value` stanza of the User Defined Variables - it will be evaluated when the configuration element will be processed
3. You can go for [ternary operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_ternary_operator) in order to convert your code into one smaller line, something like:

   ```
   ${__groovy((props.getProperty("DBsize").equals("0")) ? "SmallDB" : "LargeDB",)}
   ```

   So your configuration would be:

   [image: Groovy user defined variables]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vars.put` to add JMeter variable:

```
 import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; 

 vars.put("path",  FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir());
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.